# dev express error in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, windows-7, devexpress

I have created a web application using Devexpress trial version. I have installed the trial version in my local machine. And I have created a virtual directory( not virtual directory, its an application), in a new machine, and copied the web application from my machine to the new machine and configured the virtual directory. New machine has IIS 7 and OS is windows 7. I have copied the required dlls into 'bin' folder (new machine). In new machine application is working fine but the controls are not rendering properly. So what all steps to be followed to render the dev express controls properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also copy the DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v10.2.dll to the bin folder of your web site.  This should allow you to resolve this problem.